# Full Calendar Scheduler vis SharePoint Framework (REACT)

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar, sharepoint-online, fullcalendar-scheduler, sharepointframework

I am trying to create a SharePoint Framework webpart (based on REACT) using FullCalendar Scheduler. Full [Calendar React](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/react) daygrid works but as soon as I import Scheduler addon (@fullcalendar/resource-timeline), build failed with following error:

> The expected type comes from property 'plugins' which is declared here
>   on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes
>   & Readonly & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>

Actual code

```html
import * as React from 'react'
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/react'
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid'
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid'
import resourceTimelinePlugin from '@fullcalendar/resource-timeline'

import '@fullcalendar/core/main.css';
import '@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css';
import '@fullcalendar/timegrid/main.css';


export default class MyCall extends React.Component {

    render() {
      return (
        <FullCalendar 
            defaultView="dayGridMonth"             
            header={{
              left: 'prev,next today',
              center: 'title',
              right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
            }}
            plugins={[ dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, resourceTimelinePlugin ]} />
      )
    }
  
  }
```

if i remove the import statement for @fullcalendar/resource-timeline, it works fine but as soon as I add the import statement for scheduler, build error generated

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to include your schedulerLicenseKey.

If you want to achieve Full Calendar using SPFx in SharePoint Online, the solution below 
 from GitHub for your reference.

[spfx-react-fullcalendar](https://github.com/garima2510/SPFx-React-FullCalendar-Panel)

Comment: -Thanks for reply , I already tried with schedulerLicenseKey and resulted in same error. Thanks for sharing spfx-react-fullcalendar, will go through and update

Comment: I have gone through spfx-react-fullcalendar and not realted to full calendar scheduler.